# Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got body - Trying to create view in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, backbone.js

I am trying to create a view in Backbone and trying to load libs via node require. i am able to output to console from Model/Collection but when i start to create view i am getting error "Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got body". I tried to load View via $(function()({}) and also tried $('document').ready but no luck - any suggestions as to what i am missing or doing wrong here. Thank you

```
    var express = require('express');
    var $ = require('jQuery');
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var Backbone = require('Backbone');
    var app = express();

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

    var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: myModel,
        url: "myjson.json",
        parse: function(response) {
            return response.cars;
        }
    })

     var cars = new myCollection();

    var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: 'body',

        initialize: function() {

            cars.fetch();
            this.render();
        },
        events: {
            'click div.test': 'render'
        },
        render: function() {

            cars.each(function(myModel) {
                var _comp = myModel.get('make');
                $('div.new_test').append(_comp);

                console.log(_comp);
                return this;
            })
        }
    })

     var yourView = new myView();
```

Comment: Have you checked that, underscore and jquery libraries were really loaded?

Comment: Are you purposely returning `this` in your iterator or is that supposed to be the return value of `render`?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace from the console?

Comment: yes,the underscore and jquery libraries are loading, i checked by writing some jquery and it works..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be a problem.

```
initialize: function() {
     cars.fetch();
     this.render();
},
```

You are fetching the collection (**Which is Asynchronous**)  and immediately calling the render method.

Instead listen to the `reset` event on the collection and which will fire after the collection is populated

```
initialize: function() {
     this.listenTo(cars, 'reset', this.render);
     cars.fetch();
},
```

And move the `return this` to outside the `$.each` loop.

Comment: Thanks for response, but its not the json error, i even tried with the default values in the Model but no luck..

Comment: I was not talking about the `json` error here. What I meant was that calling render immediately after fetch will be a problen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Backbone.$ = $;` like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var $ = require('jQuery');
var _ = require('underscore');
var Backbone = require('Backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;
```